# Prove that if $G$ is abelian of order $o(G)$ and $p^\alpha|o(G)$, $p^{\alpha +1}\nmid o(G)$,(where $p$ is prime) there is a unique subgroup of $G$ of

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I was reading group theory from Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein.  I encountered a proof about the lemma in the book which states that:

> If $G$ is abelian of order $o(G)$ and $p^\alpha|o(G)$, $p^{\alpha +1}\nmid o(G)$,(where $p$ is prime) there is a unique subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{\alpha}$.

The proof given in the book was as follows:

> Suppose $T$ is another subgroup
> of $G$ of order $p^{\alpha}$,$T\neq S$. Since $G$ is abelian $ST = TS$, so that $ST$ is a subgroup of $G$. By Theorem 2.5.1, $o(ST)=\frac{o(S)o(T)}{o(S\cap T)}=\frac{p^\alpha p^\alpha}{o(S\cap T)}$ and since $S\neq T$, $o(S\cap T) < p^\alpha$;leaving us with $o(ST) = p^\gamma$, $\gamma>\alpha$. Since $ST$ is a subgroup of $G$, $o(ST)|o(G)$ thus $p^\gamma|o(G)$ violating the fact
> that $a$ is the largest power of $p$ which divides $o( G)$. Thus no such subgroup $T$ exists, and $S$ is the unique subgroup of order $p^\alpha $.

Here, Theorem 2.5.1 (in the book ) is given as If $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of $G$ then $o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$. Now, in the above proof , I am not getting how are they able to express $o(ST) $ as a power of $p$ i.e $p^\gamma $ ? How are they able to conclude it? I am not quite getting it...There may be some posts concerning the same topic but I can't seem to find it either...

Comment: Again: you need to work on the spacing around your use of punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $S$ has prime-power order, so any subgroup of $S$ also must have prime-power order.  We also know that $S \cap T$ is a subgroup of $S$, so it has prime-power order.  Thus, Theorem $2.5.1$ tells us $o(ST)$ is the product of powers of $p$ divided by a power of $p$, so it is itself a power of $p$.

Comment: Well, if $G$ is group with prime order , then by converse of Lagrange's theorem,  we can say that $G$ has only trivial subgroups . Now, $S$ and $T$ has prime power order , now, $S\cap T$ is a subgroup  of $S$ and $T$ , now, again, by converse of Lagrange's theorem,we   can  say ,  $S\cap T$ is a subgroup of prime order . This is because if $q$ is a prime such that $gcd(p,q)=1$ then, $gcd(p^\alpha,  q)=1$  so, $q$ cant be a divisor of $o(S)$ or $o(T)$  so,  $q$ cant be a factor of $o(S\cap T)$ , so, $o(S\cap T)$ must be a power of $p$ , right?...

Comment: Not prime order.  $S \cap T$ is a subgroup of prime-power order.  But yes, the conclusion is that $S \cap T$ must have order that’s a power of $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you please provide me a rigorous proof for this conclusion to hold ...and yeah ,that's a typo , but is my proof for the conclusion valid , too ? ...Thank you!...

Comment: @Franklin Except for the typo, the proof in your comment is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now...Thank you!...

Answer (score 1):

Well it's because $o(ST)$ has to be an integer, and so
$$
\dfrac{p^\alpha p^\alpha}{o(S\cap T)}
$$
is an integer too.  What could be in the denominator other than a power of $p$?